# Updating/refreshing/redrawing vector layer in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I am creating a layer groups with:

```
      var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geoJson, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'}),
      });

      var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: observationStyle
      });

      vectorLayer.set('name', observationGeoJson.features[i].properties.report_id);

      layerGroup.push(vectorLayer);

      ...


      var newLayerGroup = new ol.layer.Group({
        layers: layerGroup,
        style: style
      });
```

The GeoJson data source is then modified (the position of a point is changed). What is the best way to update the layer group? I have tried `map.updateSize();`, removing and adding the layer, `.getSource().change()` and `.getSource().clear()` + `getSource().addFeatures(newFeatures)`
But the map is always rendering both the old geometry and the new geometry.

Comment: I resolved this with a super hack that will remove the first layer group when a second layer group is present. http://pastebin.com/iZVRV29n There must be a better way...

Comment: You could post the solution you found yourself as an answer. This will bounce up the question and can be upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

the problem may be caused by the reference system or data projection.
verify your geoJson file, if it has the same reference system or data projection than your openlayers code